# Meteor - Multiple data contexts with Iron Router

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I just started using Meteor and Iron Router.

Here I'm trying to use two data contexts but appearantly I'm doing it wrong. I've googled it but it doesn't seem this is a very common problem, but I guess it got to be possible to pass on two or more data contexts, right?

This is my routing.js

```
Router.route('/package/:_id', function () {
      //Returns the selected/clicked package
      var package = Packages.findOne({_id: this.params._id});
      //Returns all items in Items collection.
      var listItems = Items.find();
      this.render('PackageDetails', {data: package, listItems});
    });
```

My template in which I'm trying to use data from the both contexts (one to populate a dropdownlist and one to show data of selected package

```
<template name="PackageDetails">
    <label class="label label-default">Item type: </label><p>{{ item }}</p>
    <label class="label label-default">Quantity: </label><p>{{ quantity }}</p>
    <label class="label label-default">Id: </label><p>{{ _id }}</p>

    <form class="change-state">
        <div class="input-group">
        {{> sAlert}}
        <select class="form-control" name="state">
            <option selected="true" disabled>Select State</option>
            {{#each states}}
                <option>{{name}}</option>
            {{/each}}
        </select>
        </div><br>

        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Change state" class="btn btn-success"/>
        </div>
    </form><br>
</template>
```

I solved it by using helpers on the template which returned the data, but would prefer to get it all from the routing.

So any ideas about this? Is there a better approach to achieve this or is it possible to pass two data contexts via Iron Router, in that case, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data object declaring syntax is wrong, it should be :

```
this.render('PackageDetails', {
  data: {
    package: package,
    listItems: listItems
  }
});
```

Then in your template, you can reference the data context using `{{package.property}}` and `{{#each listItems}}`.

Comment: Thanks! I already tried a few different syntaxes similar to this one actually but appearantly not like this. Btw, do you know the differences between this.route and Router.route, guess it's basically the same (older vs newer syntax?). Seen them both but don't know which to use...

Comment: There's no difference but use `Router.route`, it's the newer syntax.